# Why do I get IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the `IndexError` with a  list. My code looks like this:

```
for x in range(len(MAIN_list[0])):
                   print(x)
                   print(MAIN_list[9][x])
                   print(MAIN_list[10][x])
                   print(MAIN_list[0][x] + "; " + MAIN_list[1][x] + \
                         "; " + MAIN_list[2][x] + "; " + MAIN_list[3][x] + \
                         "; " + MAIN_list[4][x] + "; " + MAIN_list[5][x] + \
                         "; " + MAIN_list[6][x] + "; " + MAIN_list[7][x] + \
                         "; " + MAIN_list[8][x] + "; " + MAIN_list[9][x] + \
                         "; " + MAIN_list[10][x])
```

Now, the output is:

```
0
cross
tick
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michele2\Desktop\Arcrate\MyCASH\Python Code\Scraping\Scraping1.3(clean)TEST.py", line 246, in <module>
    "; " + MAIN_list[10][x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know that you'd usually get this error for variables outside the actual length of the list, but here I get the right output when I call it singularly (ie. row 3 of the output) but not when I try to print the list as a whole. Any though would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: what appens if you do `print(MAIN_list)`?

Comment: Do a `print [len(x) for x in MAIN_list]` - at least one of the sublists is shorter than `MAIN_list[0]`. For Exceptions in a multiline statements, a traceback will only show the last line; this doesn't mean the error has to be exactly there.

Answer (score 0):

The only point I can see is that one of your lists is by accident shorter than the others.

You have structured your data in a very strange way - column-wise instead of row-wise.

Normally, you would have `MAIN_list` a list of rows (lists or tuples). Then you would access with `MAIN_list[row][column]` and could iterate in the right order over them.

In your case, things are different. The first point to check could be

```
for x in range(11):
    print(len(MAIN_list[x]))
```

iterating over the columns and checking their length. Maybe one is empty...

BTW, once you have found the reason and have fixed it, you might want to simplify your expression:

```
print("; ".join(MAIN_list[i][x] for i in range(11)))
```